# Unable to capture response.json() in playwright

Tags: javascript, webautomation, playwright

I am trying to capture json response using playwright. I keep on getting Promise pending. However under headless:false mode i can see the data is being received and populated on the browser. I have just started playing with Playwright and also not very familiar with "Promise".

What i have tried is as below:

```
(async () => {
        let browser = await firefox.launch({headless: true, userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'});
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        page.waitForResponse(async(response) => {
            if (response.url().includes('/abcd') && response.status() == 200) {
                let resp = await response.json();
                console.log(resp);
            }
        });
        await page.goto('https://myurl.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle', timeout: 30000});
        await page.waitForTimeout(20000);
        await browser.close();
})
```

What am i doing wrong? I have tried increasing timeout. Doesnot help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `waitForResponse` won't handle your async function. You could do something like this:

```js
(async () => {
  let browser = await firefox.launch({headless: true, userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'});
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  const promise page.waitForResponse(/abcd/); // This is a regex to match the url
  await page.goto('https://myurl.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle', timeout: 30000});
  var response = await promise; // here we wait for the promise to be fullfiled. 
  let resp = await response.json();
  console.log(resp);
  await browser.close();
})
```

Comment: Thank You!! Worked and more importantly understood Promise better :)

Comment: Why exactly does `waitForResponse` not handle it im curious? Shouldn't the predicate not get ran inside `waitForResponse` until it's actually triggered via the API call happening later?

Comment: @msmith1114 the question would be what do you think that should wait for the waitForResponse in the original code?

Answer (score 0):

`Page` [`goto` method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-goto) returns `Response` object which has [`json` method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-response#response-json).

```
const response = await page.goto('https://test');

await response.json();
```