# How to save requests' response body using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, webautomation, playwright

I need to intercept network request and save it's response body to variable, so I can perform assertions with values, that are displayed on UI, but when I try to access variable which is supposed to contain saved response body I receive [object Object] instead of a valid body.

JSON.stringify also doesn't fix the problem, as my variable becomes `{"_type":"Page","_guid":"page@"}` instead of an actual response.

Here's the code:

```
const resp = await page.on('response', async response => {
  if (response.url().includes('/some_url/') && response.status() === 200) {
    console.log('BODY() ' + (await response.body())); //logs valid JSON response body
    return await response.body();
  }
})
console.log('RESPONSE' + resp); //logs RESPONSE[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been nearly a year since I asked this question.
There's also another way to save responses using async predicate functions (especially useful with graphql, where there's only one endpoint)

```
    const [response] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForResponse(async response => {
            const text = await response.text();
            return text.includes(`some response text, that we need to intercept`);
        })
    ]);
    return response.json();
```

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4535

Answer (score 16):

I would use `waitForResponse` that will return the `response` matching the predicate. The predicate should return `true` or `false`. Once the and then you evaluate the response:

```
const response = await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('/some_url/') && response.status() === 200);
console.log('RESPONSE ' + (await response.body()));
```

Comment: Quite hard to follow the code here in the comment. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: nevermind, I fixed the problem by reading your answer to another question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67020417/11540378

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

`page.on` sets an event of type `'response'` to be handled by the arrow function that is set starting on the first line
: `async response => {...`.

When we set an event such as this one, we get output but the output is not the response itself. If you want to print the entire response you should do it inside the arrow function just before you return:

```js
    ...
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response);
    return await response.body();
```

Nit: there's no need to `await` on a return, the last line can be rewritten to:

```js
    return response.body();
```

Comment: Thanks for advice
But is there an any way to access response body outside of an arrow function?

Comment: @VladimirKrygin not from here because this code executes before a request entered...